# Can't escape the space when changing Shell in nvim

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, neovim

I'm trying to change the nvim shell to Powershell 7, i've tried adding `set shell=powershell` and it works, the problem is that doing that way comes with a **massive slowdown** on every action what i perform in nvim *(saving, using nvim-tree, even starting up nvim)*. Reading a bit online found someone who solved this issue by manually adding the shell path instead of the `set shell=powershell` mentioned before, behind the idea that the powershell being used was the 32-bit one instead of the 64.

So, i've tried to do the same and added this.

`set shell=C:/Program\ Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe`

But that didn't work, every time i've tried to open the terminal with `:term` i got

`E475: Invalid value for argument cmd: 'C:/Program' is not executable`

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On the off chance that it is `cmd.exe` that is interpreting the executable path (which would be curious, given that you're trying to _replace_ `cmd.exe` as the shell), try `^` instead of `\ ` as the escape character.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did what you said but i got the same error but with the `^` instead of the `\ `

Comment: Try "double quoting"

Comment: What about `set shell=pwsh.exe`?

Comment: `set shell=\"C:/Program\ Files/...."\ `